# display axes in a circle with equal spacing in between

Tags: d3.js

As you can see from [this example by Mike Bostock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2066415), it is possible to display the axis to a graph in a circle. In the linked to example, there are three axis (with the areas in between of equal size) which seemed to be created by this line of code

```
var angle = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(d3.range(4)).rangePoints([0, 2 * Math.PI]),
```

plus

```
svg.selectAll(".axis")
    .data(d3.range(3))
  .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + degrees(angle(d)) + ")"; })
    .attr("x1", radius.range()[0])
    .attr("x2", radius.range()[1]);
```

Playing around with that example, I was able to create a graph with six axes (**with equal spacing between each axis**) that covered the whole circle using this code

```
var angle = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]).range([0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225])
```

and then

```
svg.selectAll(".axis").data(d3.range(7))
//code omitted
```

However, I haven't been able to create a circle with 9 axes (with equal spacing in between) by doing this (as I expected it would)

```
var angle = d3.scale.ordinal()
   .domain(["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"])
  .range([0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315, 360]);

svg.selectAll(".axis").data(d3.range(10))
    //code omitted
```

The result of doing this is that the axes start to go around the circle a second time.

**Question:** is there a pattern that can be followed to have an arbitrary number of axes displayed in a circle with equal spacing in between each? If so, please explain the d3 principles behind the two successful attempts and the one unsuccessful attempt shown and linked to above.

**Update**

Although removing the calls to degrees, puts the axes in the right position, (and then removing the call to degrees in the nodes code puts the nodes on the axes in the right axes), the links are not lining up properly i.e. they are not starting and ending on the axes, but rather floating unanchored. You can see the problem in this image[image]

This is the code for the links (notice that it doesn't have a call to degrees)

```
svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(linx)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("class", function(d) {  return "link " + d.Class})
    .attr("d", link()
    .angle(function(d) { return angle(d.X); })
    .radius(function(d) { return radius(d.Y); }))
    .on("mouseover", linkMouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout);
```

It calls a link function (which also doens't have a call to degrees, so I don't know why the links are starting and ending at the *old* position of the axes) that I got from Mike Bostock's hive implementation

```
function link() {

       var source = function(d) { return d.Source; },
      target = function(d) { return d.Target; },
      angle = function(d) { return d.angle; },
      startRadius = function(d) { return d.radius; },
      endRadius = startRadius,
      arcOffset = -Math.PI / 2;

  function link(d, i) {
    // console.log(d, i, "interior link func");
    var s = node(source, this, d, i),
        t = node(target, this, d, i),
        x;
    if (t.a < s.a) x = t, t = s, s = x;
    if (t.a - s.a > Math.PI) s.a += 2 * Math.PI;
    var a1 = s.a + (t.a - s.a) / 3,
        a2 = t.a - (t.a - s.a) / 3;
    return s.r0 - s.r1 || t.r0 - t.r1
        ? "M" + Math.cos(s.a) * s.r0 + "," + Math.sin(s.a) * s.r0
        + "L" + Math.cos(s.a) * s.r1 + "," + Math.sin(s.a) * s.r1
        + "C" + Math.cos(a1) * s.r1 + "," + Math.sin(a1) * s.r1
        + " " + Math.cos(a2) * t.r1 + "," + Math.sin(a2) * t.r1
        + " " + Math.cos(t.a) * t.r1 + "," + Math.sin(t.a) * t.r1
        + "L" + Math.cos(t.a) * t.r0 + "," + Math.sin(t.a) * t.r0
        + "C" + Math.cos(a2) * t.r0 + "," + Math.sin(a2) * t.r0
        + " " + Math.cos(a1) * s.r0 + "," + Math.sin(a1) * s.r0
        + " " + Math.cos(s.a) * s.r0 + "," + Math.sin(s.a) * s.r0
        : "M" + Math.cos(s.a) * s.r0 + "," + Math.sin(s.a) * s.r0
        + "C" + Math.cos(a1) * s.r1 + "," + Math.sin(a1) * s.r1
        + " " + Math.cos(a2) * t.r1 + "," + Math.sin(a2) * t.r1
        + " " + Math.cos(t.a) * t.r1 + "," + Math.sin(t.a) * t.r1;
  }

  function node(method, thiz, d, i) {
    var node = method.call(thiz, d, i),
        a = +(typeof angle === "function" ? angle.call(thiz, node, i) : angle) + arcOffset,
        r0 = +(typeof startRadius === "function" ? startRadius.call(thiz, node, i) : startRadius),
        r1 = (startRadius === endRadius ? r0 : +(typeof endRadius === "function" ? endRadius.call(thiz, node, i) : endRadius));
    return {r0: r0, r1: r1, a: a};
  }

  link.source = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return source;
    source = _;
    return link;
  };

  link.target = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return target;
    target = _;
    return link;
  };

  link.angle = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return angle;
    angle = _;
    return link;
  };

  link.radius = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return startRadius;
    startRadius = endRadius = _;
    return link;
  };

  link.startRadius = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return startRadius;
    startRadius = _;
    return link;
  };

  link.endRadius = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return endRadius;
    endRadius = _;
    return link;
  };

  return link;
}
```

Comment: You have angles in degrees already, you don't need to use the `degree` function. If you remove the call to that everything should work fine.

Comment: Thank you that worked. Didn't realize it was so easy, because I used the degree function and had hard coded angles too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have angles in degrees already, you don't need to use the `degree()` function. If you remove the call to that everything will work fine.

Comment: ok thank you,this works for the axis (and for nodes when I remove the call to degrees from nodes) but for some reason the links are starting and ending from the position where the axis (and degrees) would be if the degrees function had been called,  even though the degrees function isn't called for links. Can you explain?

Comment: ok, sorry for the delay, since it's closely related to the OP, I updated the OP showing the problem with the links and the code  (rather than ask a new question). However if you feel it should be  a new question please let me know and I will post it as such.

Comment: Could you provide a complete example that allows to reproduce the problem please?

Comment: Ok, here's a link to jsfiddle with a complete example that reproduces the problem https://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/wowem1b1/ . It only uses two nodes and one link. You can see the link thinks the nodes are in the position where they would be if the call to `degrees` hadn't been commented out (which you can see by uncommenting the relevant lines of code in the two blocks where d3 appends the nodes and links in my draw function). Please let me know if you have any questions.  (also notice that if you uncomment the call the degrees, that the axes no longer align but the links and nodes align)

Comment: by the way, there's a couple properties on the nodes and link objects that are not used by the d3 code (and which you can ignore).

Comment: Not entirely sure what's happening there, but your angles are off by 90 degrees and need to be in radians and not degrees for the links: https://jsfiddle.net/wowem1b1/1